# Mongodb find_and_update $ne issue

Tags: mongodb

I have a document:

active -> array of active id's

new_active -> array of active id's with some details

Now, I would like to add a new ID to active, but only if it's not present in new_active.
I dont want to change my schema, I would rather like to understand why first version of the code works perfectly fine, while second one does not.

In the first code I have used arrays for both active & new_active, and this works fine:

`a = MongoMapper.database.collection(:papers).find_and_modify(
        :query => {
          :active => {
            '$nin' => [paper_id]
          },
          :new_active =>  {'$ne' => [paper_id]} #I know, $nin can also be used
        },
        :update => {
          '$push' =>{
            :active => paper_id,
          }
        },
        :upsert => false,
        :new => true`

This code works fine and pushes ID to the active if it is not present in both arrays.
Now, I wanted to have an array of hashes/ dicts in new_active. This is when problem occurred.
The reason for using `$ne` instead of `$nin` is that `$ne` should return a result it the field doesn't have particular value OR the field doesn't exist. In this case, `paper_id` field in the `new_active` doesn't exist:
`a = MongoMapper.database.collection(:papers).find_and_modify(
        :query => {
          :active => {
            '$nin' => [paper_id]
          },
          :new_active => {
            :paper_id => {'$ne' => [paper_id]}
          }
        },
        :update => {
          '$push' =>{
            :active => paper_id,
          }
        },
        :upsert => false,
        :new => true`

This code doesnt push paper_id into the active array. Why?

Comment: why not use $addToSet instead of $push here?

Comment: @VitalyMuminov because I want to maintain order while adding. And as stated above "I dont want to change my schema, I would rather like to understand why first version of the code works perfectly fine, while second one does not."

Comment: @VitalyMuminov plus in my final version of the code I will use array of hashes anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `{'$nin' => [paper_id]}` is equivalent to `{'$ne' => paper_id}`, not `{'$ne' => [paper_id]}`.

Comment: Also, you should be able to use `$ne` in place of a single-item `$nin`; [the current reference manual page for `$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#op._S_ne) says: `This includes documents that do not contain the field.`